# File uploading in fultter webview

Tags: flutter, flutterwebviewplugin

I am using fluter webview for android and iOS apps. In the app, the page contains an HTML form where one of the fields is file uploading via dropzone.

[image: Dropzone]

If I open the page in the browser and press the Choose File button, file chooser pops up and everything is working fine, but when I press the Choose File button in the webview nothing happens.

I am following this github issue initiated by flutter developers - https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27924

Any ideas how to make this work?